# Angular 6: Host binding in directive is not two way binding?

Tags: javascript, angular, resize, textarea, angular2-hostbinding

I am working on Angular 6 on a pretty simple example.

I am creating a Directive that I can put on my textareas so that they resize themselves automatically.

However, I have an issue using host binding. I want to check if resize is needed before resizing, but I cannot check: this.height gives undefined by default.

Even worse, if it has been resized manually, this.height remains undefined anyway.

I've tried using the @Input decorator on top of the @HostBinding, but this just sets an initial value, and then when resizing, height doesn't match the real size of the element anymore.

I can't seem to find out why it doesn't work, could you please help ?

Also I am conscious that an alternative to what I'm trying to do would be to just set the height of my directive to the native element scrollheight without checking prior, but then I wouldn't understand why my height value is undefined/doesn't dynamically update.

Here is my code:

**simple.component.html**

```
<textarea type="text"
class="form-control mb-1"
appAutoResizeTextArea></textarea>
```

**simple.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-simple-component',
  templateUrl: './simple.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./simple.component.css']
})
export class SimpleComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**auto-resize-text-area.directive.ts**

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Renderer2, HostBinding, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appAutoResizeTextArea]',
})
export class AutoResizeTextAreaDirective {
  @HostBinding('style.height.px') height;

  @HostListener('input')
  onKeyDown(){
    console.log(this.height); // gives 'undefined'
    if(this.height < this.el.nativeElement.scrollHeight || this.height > this.el.nativeElement.scrollHeight)
      this.height = this.el.nativeElement.scrollHeight;
  }
  constructor(private el:ElementRef, private renderer:Renderer2) { }

}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: I think that a textarea element doesn't have an initial height property set, only when you set it explicitly (in html, css or js)

Comment: Ok, in this case there must be a property somewhere at the time of rendering, right ? In the shadow dom maybe ?

Comment: maybe you can use [getBoundingClientRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) method